# Objective-C NSUrlConnection : No cookie return

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharepoint, cookies, nsurlconnection

I am working with a NTLM Server authentification (SharePoint), I manage to make a GET request using NSURLConnection and credentials.

What I want is to get the session cookies from that request, like on a desktop, and put them into [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage], for future connection in a WebView.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [HTTPResponse allHeaderFields]); // Log below
    NSArray *cookies = [NSHTTPCookie
                cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[HTTPResponse allHeaderFields]
                forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://domain.com"]];

    NSLog(@"How many Cookies: %d", cookies.count); // GOT 0 HERE

    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:cookies forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://domain.com"] mainDocumentURL:nil];

}
```

I have this response which is not a cookie I think (I changed the values):

```
Response: {
        "Cache-Control" = "private,max-age=0";
        Connection = "Keep-Alive";
        "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
        "Content-Length" = 1536;
        "Content-Type" = "text/html";
        Date = "Thu, 03 Jul 2014 09:00:35 GMT";
        Etag = "\"{F1F0AAgregr-41DA-AgergA26-51A51B019910},3\"";
        Expires = "Wed, 18 Jun 2014 09:00:36 GMT";
        "Last-Modified" = "Fri, 02 May 2014 13:35:13 GMT";
        MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices = "14.0.0.6120";
        "Persistent-Auth" = true;
        "Public-Extension" = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2";
        ResourceTag = "rt:F1F0AAE2gerge1B019gerg000003";
        SPRequestGuid = "975dccbgregergrgbbeff4f5b5";
        Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
        Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
        "X-MS-InvokeApp" = "1; RequireReadOnly";
        "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
        "X-SharePointHealthScore" = 0;
    }
```

I know that the cookie is suppose to have for Expires/Max-Age the value Session.
Do you have any idea if what I want to do is possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect cookie in method - `- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`

As per documentation this method is used for - `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` is called whenever an connection determines that it must change URLs in order to continue loading a request. This gives the delegate an opportunity inspect and if necessary modify a request & inspecting the response.

So use like -

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [HTTPResponse allHeaderFields]); // Log below
    NSArray *cookies = [NSHTTPCookie
                cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[HTTPResponse allHeaderFields]
                forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://domain.com"]];

    NSLog(@"How many Cookies: %d", cookies.count); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this code, and the [HTTPResponse allHeaderFields] is null, even the response is null. This function is called before all the other but I don't have a response not empty like in didReceiveResponse

Comment: and in didReceiveResponse you are receiving response?

Comment: Yes, the response is the second block of code I posted in my question. When I try to convert it into a cookie it create an empty array